# Operator "|=" versus "+="

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

Is there any difference between the two?

If not, then why is `|=` implemented when we can just use the more well-known `+=`?  I think it may just be for convenience, to accompany `&=`, which I don't think there is an alternative for.

Comment: Is in Python the `|` operator exactly the same as `+`? I.e., does `x = 1 | 3` evaluate to the same result as `x = 1 + 3`? In other languages the behavior is *radically* different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to understand bitwise operations:
for example:

```
a = 2
a |= 2
```

will result in `a = 2`

This is since the `|` (or) operator works like this:
`2` in binary is represented as `10`, and `10|10` could be done in this way:

`10`
`10`
___
`10`

You look at each column, and if there is a `1` in one of the rows, in the result row you will also have a `1`.

when you calculate `2|1` you can get a similar result to `2 + 1` since `1` in binary is `01` and the operation translates to:

`10`
`01`
___
`11`

And `11` in binary is `3` in decimal.

Answer (score 5):

Of course there's a difference:

```
a = 1
a |= 1
print a
```

vs.

```
a = 1
a += 1
print a
```

One is for addition, the other is for bitwise or operation. They might also be overloaded in different ways for other types.

Comment: Woops, I should have known that.

Comment: @onepiece: Yes, you should have. Binary adder circuits would be much simpler if that were the case. :) `a|b` == `a+b` iff `a&b` == 0.